# Need explanation of hfile bulk load using uncommitted iterator and rollback

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have inherited a piece of Scala code that uses an odd approach to inserting data into Phoenix HBase tables.  It opens a JDBC connection and executes an UPSERT statement against the target. It then obtains an 'UncommittedDataIterator' and accumulates... something from the connection handle before rolling back the transaction.  The collected data is assembled into a Spark RDD and eventually written to an hfile that is, in turn, bulk-loaded to the target table.

My question is this:  What is the rationale for this logic?  Where can I find a coherent explanation of it?  I've found at least one other reference to this approach, but there was not attribution for it.  If this idiom is documented or explained anywhere, would appreciate a link.